# Create a styled Dropdown like on jquery UI

Tags: jquery, select

On http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ at the top right corner, you can see a dropdown that says "Theme: UI Lightness" by default.

I'd love to create such an interactive element in my web application. Does anyone know of a good jquery plugin to easily do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A nice example of a plugin exists [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/). Enabled by nothing more than `$('select').selectmenu();`.

Comment: any word on the future for this? it seems to be incompatible with jquery-ui 1.8 ?

Comment: I found a possible update for it: http://devermind.com/aspnet/jquery-selectmenu-widget-for-jquery-ui-1-8/ according to the content, it should work with 1.8 but I did not try it yet, let me know if it works fine

Comment: Looks like that link is broken. Here's a link to the blog post (http://devermind.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/jquery-selectmenu-widget-for-jquery-ui-1-8/) and the github (https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui).

Comment: @Spir I checked the link in my answer; it appears to work just fine.

Comment: Indeed but the other one are dead.