# IE8 not applying font-weight : bold and text-decoration : underline properties

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a <strike>dropdown</strike> `select` element in which few of the `option`s need to be shown as bold and underline. I have defined some CSS below:

`.OptioncBold{ font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;}`

This is working fine in Firefox, but not in IE8. When I debug it in IE using the developer tools, it even shows the class being added on that particular `option` along with both the properties. However, when I see the <strike>dropdown</strike> `select` element, the `option` is neither bold nor underlined. I've read many posts related to this, but could not find anything which helped.

Thanks for your time and help.

Anup

Comment: Can you try adding the style elements directly to the dropdown and let me know if that makes any difference?

Comment: Form elements (selects in particular) have wildly varying styles that depend not only on the browser implementing them, but also the operating system the client is on. Solutions would be to use a hacky workaround/plugin or to just drop the style idea completely.

Comment: Does adding a IE7 compatibility tag to the page make it work? Is there a IE7 compatibility tag already on the page? If so try removing it.

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655625/styling-options-in-bold-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @James Johnson: I tried adding the styles directly to the options..this also did not work.. – Anup Dhiran 0 secs ago

Comment: @ Matt McDonald : Unfortunately, I can not drop the idea not to add the styles. This is a business requirement.

Comment: @Ali : I am not aware much about IE7 compatibility tag, can you please help me on that on how to add/remove it, what is it ?

Comment: This tag needs to be first in the `<head>` (before any css):
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />` having this meta tag in the head will force IE8 to use IE7 compatibility mode.

Comment: @Ali..even that did not work :( adding or removing it..

Comment: @tw16 : this helped a lot. I tried the plug in given in the example for that question..it's not working though.I am working on the alternatives..will let everyone know if I am able to find something..Thanks all for your help..

Answer (score 0):

It is not working in ie, you can try a plugin for custom selectboxes.