# Select dropdown option bold in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

Is there any way to make an `<option>` tag bold in a `select` box in Chrome and IE using CSS? It's working in Firefox.

```css
option.red {
    background-color: #cc0000; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<select name="color">
    <option class="red" value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

This is the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/cssselect-dropdown-option), but there was no answer.

Comment: Congratulations; the idiotic Chrome developers have now made dropdowns bold by default. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. The most likely solution you'll find "out there" would be to add a surrounding span with hard coded style, but neither IE (7) nor Firefox (3.0.12) honor this.

What you can do is use a JavaScript solution to give you the appearance of a select without actually using a select.

And here's a great "howto" on how to do it: http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/

Comment: Is there any way to do it with javascript??

Answer (score 0):

I used `<option class="bold">Bold Text here</option>`

with CSS:

```
option.bold {
     font-weight:bold;
}
```

and it worked for Firefox (Mac and Windows) and for IE11, but not for Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome doesn't allow bold font on option tag, you can use `text-shadow` property like

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black;
```

It will give same appearance of bold and work on all the browsers.

Comment: This did not have any effect on the option for me in Chrome.