# Change select box option background color

Tags: html, css, html-select, background-color

I have a select box and I'm trying to change the background color of the options when the select box has been clicked and shows all the options.

```css
body {
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/black_linen_v2.png) repeat;
}

select {
  margin: 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option val="">Please choose</option>
  <option val="1">Option 1</option>
  <option val="2">Option 2</option>
  <option val="3">Option 3</option>
  <option val="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You need to put `background-color` on the `option` tag and not the `select` tag...

```css
select option {
  margin: 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

If you want to style each one of the `option` tags.. use the css `attribute` selector:

```css
select option {
  margin: 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

select option[value="1"] {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}

select option[value="2"] {
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.3);
}

select option[value="3"] {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
}

select option[value="4"] {
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Please choose</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I took away the rgba option and seems to use black now which will do :)

Comment: You could use the CSS `:nth-child(1..n)` selector instead.

Comment: You probably should not use the attribute selector. You probably want to use the n-th-child or give each option a class instead.

Comment: How can I change bg-color of option while hover?

Comment: "Run code snippet" still have dark grey background,

Comment: This doesnt work in Safari 15. Inspecting the element shows the CSS background, but the select box doesnt have the style

Comment: this does not work in the current version of chrome for me

Answer (score 24):

I don't know if you've considered it or not but if your application is based on coloring various groupings of items you should probably use the `<optgroup>` tag coupled with a class for further referencing. For example:

```css
.green option {
  background-color: #0F0;
}

.blue option {
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Numbers" class="green">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Letters" class="blue">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Does nothing in Chrome on OSX

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can set this by the opposite way:

```
select { /* desired background */ }
option:not(:checked) { background: #fff; }
```

Check it working bellow:

```css
select {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

option:not(:checked) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option val="">Select Option</option>
  <option val="1">Option 1</option>
  <option val="2">Option 2</option>
  <option val="3">Option 3</option>
  <option val="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @aswzen actually in Chrome is working for me (v65) but not in Firefox Quantum (v59).

Comment: how does this code work for these people, not even the code snippet shows desired result for me!

Comment: yes, even "Run code snipped" shows default gray background, very general dark grey background. i can not share screenshot or snippet here, i wanted to share what i am seeing

Comment: Does not answer the question--OP wants to change the background-color of the options when the menu is expanded, not the background-color of the default/currently-selected option when the menu is closed.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Similar to some of the answers, but not really stated, is to add a class to the actual option tag and use css classes...this is currently working for me without issue on IE (see above ss).

```
<select id="reviewAction">
<option class="greenColor">Accept and Advance Status</option>
<option class="redColor">Return for Modifications</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.greenColor{
    background-color: #33CC33;
}
.redColor{
    background-color: #E60000;
}
```

Comment: _How_ you select the element is irrelevant--you are repeating the answer from 1 year prior (which happens to be the top answer), which is applying `background-color` to the `option` tag. Please only provide _novel_ solutions to questions!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use Javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById('selectID').value == '1') {
       document.getElementById('optionID').style.color = '#000';
```

(Not as clean as the CSS attribute selector, but more powerful)

Answer (score 2):

My selects would not color the background until I added !important to the style.

```
    input, select, select option{background-color:#FFE !important}
```

Comment: The use of !important should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: `!important` is also completely irrelevant unless you have other styles, which is not a concern for this question. As such this repeats numerous answers, including the [top one from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836286/).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to style the `<options>` within a `<select>`, consider switching to a Javascript/CSS based drop down such as http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns or https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/. This because browsers such as IE [do not allow styling of options within `<select>` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655625/styling-options-in-bold-in-internet-explorer).  Chrome/OSX also has this problem - you cannot style options.

However a warning is attached to that approach. These types of menus work very differently on mobile platforms because native elements aren't used. They can have annoying quirks on desktop as well. My advice is 1) don't write your own and 2) find a library that's been really well tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$htmlIngressCss='<style>';
$multiOptions = array("" => "All");
$resIn = $this->commonDB->getIngressTrunk();
while ($row = $resIn->fetch()) {
    if($row['IsActive']==0){
        $htmlIngressCss .= '.ingressClass select, option[value="'.$row['TrunkInfoID'].'"] {color:red;font-weight:bold;}';
    }
    $multiOptions[$row['TrunkInfoID']] = $row['IngressTrunkName'];
}
$htmlIngressCss.='</style>';
```

add `$htmlIngressCss` in your html portion :)