# setting the background color of a option under select

Tags: html, css

I found the following answer [How to change select box option background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color) but it did not work for me.

I have the following list in my html file

```
<select>
<option value="item 1" ></option>
<option value="item 2" ></option>
<option value="item 3"></option>
</select>
```

and the following css

```
select option[value="item 1"]{
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
}
```

but i am still getting an empty list with no background colors. 
What I am trying to get is some sort of a drop down with just colors and no text

something like this

[image]

thanks

Comment: this works fine, just move the selection to a different option and you will see that the first element is grey, to get what the image shows you would need to make a custom select box, using html/css/javascript

Comment: does not work for me:( also maybe this is not what I am looking for? as my image demonstrate I kind of want to always see the color in the drop down

Comment: as i mention to get what you want you cannot do with a regular select input box you would need to create a custom select box out of like divs or ul/li lists or other html elements and style them with css and use javascript to make it function.

Comment: Will you be able to give me some pointers on how to implement such a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Go with `nth-child()` instead :

```
select option:nth-child(1) {
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
}
```

Then you are also not needed to change your CSS every time you change the values of the options.

---

Edit - I think you do

```css
select option:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
select option:nth-child(2) {
    background: yellow;
}
select option:nth-child(3) {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option value="item 1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
<option value="item 2">&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
<option value="item 3">&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: as Patrick said this probably won't work for what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You see an empty list because the `option` elements are empty. You cannot expect to be able to see the background of an empty area. But you can include e.g. a no-break space in the `option` element:

```
<option value="item 1" >&nbsp;</option>
```

You may still have problems with some browsers (styling of `option` elements has many oddities and browser differences, and the background and text color of the currently selected option tend to be fixed, by the browser, rather than CSS-settable).

A completely different approach is probably needed, though. While waiting for `<input type=color>` to be implemented during a decade or two, you need to set up color choices differently. There are many existing libraries that contain code for such things, but they tend to have accessility problems. Perhaps the simplest approach is to contructs simple use a table with radio buttons in one column, color samples *and* corresponding color names in another. Here, too, you would need to remember to set some content, like no-break space, into the element you use to present a color sample using a background color.