# Change background on drop down...seems simple enough

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to change the background color on a dropdown menu.

http://www.vintageandretro.com.au/1940s-south-california-tourist-cushion/

Look at the quantity drop down.  I want the background to be a different color.  I tried changing the `div.selector` in the custom.css file but it still overrides it back to white.

```
div.selector {
  width: 200px;
  color: #444440;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #000000 url(../../BrideToBe/images/theme/icon_arrow_down.png) no-repeat    right center !important;
  border: 1px dashed #d4d3d3;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  min-height: 28px !important;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 3px 0 !important;`
}
```

To test, I've even removed the url to the arrow down icon, and it still appears.  As if it is somehow being overridden.

Thanks!

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color

Comment: although styling dropdown elements via css is very limited. I'd suggest considering some jQuery alternative, like jQuery Select2 or so..

Comment: I have changed color to black in the dom of your website and it worked `url("../../BrideToBe/images/theme/icon_arrow_down.png") no-repeat scroll right center #000000 !important` You don't even need `!important` rule

Comment: David, BigCommerce does a lot of its HTML through Snippets and such and so I can't directly reach the dropdown code.

LorDex, I've thought about jQuery and I got it to work with the dropdown list, but not the actual box

Morpheus, I can change it using Google's inspect but it won't do it if I edit the CSS..as if it's somehow being overridden.