# How to check if my form is valid after click on `add_button` and if is not than change color of input/select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**HTML:**

```
<select id="id_myselect" name="myselect">
   <option value="0">---------</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="7">2</option>
   <option value="10">3</option>
</select>

<select id="id_book" name="book">
   <option value="0">---------</option>
   <option value="1">Book1</option>
</select>

<input id="id_number" name="number" type="number" />
<div id="add_button">Add</div>
```

How to check if my form is valid after click on `add_button` and if is not than change color of input/select?

**My try with jQuery:**

```
if($( "#id_myselect option:selected" ).val() == 0){
       $("#id_myselect").addClass( "error" );
    }
else if($( "#id_book option:selected" ).val() == 0){
       $("#id_book").addClass( "error" );
}    

else if($( "id_number" ).val() <= 0){
       $("#id_number").addClass( "error" );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick of add_button Check `$('.error').length`. If it is zero then there is no error:

```
 $('#add_button').on('click',function(){
     if($('.error').length!=0){
        console.log('Error exist');
     }
 });
```

And when it comes to changing color, add css to `.error` class.

Comment: Can I add background color for `select` input?

Comment: @user3386824 you can refer this to change color of select http://stackoverflow.com/a/12836286/2567813

Comment: You should clear the error class from all element on every add_button click.

Comment: @user3386824:problem still persists?? can you create the fiddle??

Answer (score 1):

Try this on `clicking` of a `div` like

```
$(function(){
    $('#add_button').on('click',function(){
        if($( "#id_myselect" ).val() == 0){// remove option:selected
           $("#id_myselect").addClass( "error" );
        }else if($( "#id_book" ).val() == 0){// remove option:selected
           $("#id_book").addClass( "error" );
        }    
        else if($( "#id_number" ).val() <= 0){
           $("#id_number").addClass( "error" );
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uj69u/)