# Control open/close of <select> with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a custom HTML5 `<select>` menu. By design, I'm trying to change the color of the `select` elements depending on the selected element. Basically I need `#555555` color when the menu is opened and when the element selected is not the first one, and #c7cacb for closed menu with the first element selected.

The problem comes when the user opens the menu, selects the first option, and then opens the menu once again: all elements are #c7cacb. It would be easy to control color if I got the menu open|close status with jQuery (I didn't find the way how) or other way (stack here). How can I do this?

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // wrap all selectors to add ::after in css
  $('select:not([disabled])').wrap('<label class="dropdown">');
  $('select[disabled]').wrap('<label class="dropdownDisabled">');
  // controlling color of elements
  $('select').click(function(){
    var thisDropdown= $(this);
    if($(thisDropdown).prop('selectedIndex') == 0){
      thisDropdown.css('color', '#555555');
      thisDropdown.click( function(){ 
        if($(thisDropdown).prop('selectedIndex') == 0) {
          thisDropdown.css('color', '#c7cacb');
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

```css
/*dropdown styling*/
select {
  width: 230px;
  height: 46px;
  background: #f1f5f8;
  color:#c7cacb;
  font-size: 16pt;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d6d5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
select::-ms-expand {/*removing dropdown arrow for IE*/
  display: none;
}
.dropdownlabel {display: block; font-size: 16pt; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #d7d6d5}
label.dropdown::after {/*adding custom arrow*/
    content: "\e90e";
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #555555;
 display:inline-block;
 box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-left: -32px;
    pointer-events :none; /* let the click pass trough */
}

select[disabled] {
 color: #c7cacb;
 border: 2px solid #e4e5e6;
}

label.dropdownDisabled::after {
    content: "\e90e";
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #d3d5d7;
 display:inline-block;
 box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-left: -32px;
    pointer-events :none; /* let the click pass trough */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="selected" class="dropdownlabel">Dropdown label</label>
<select name="selected">
  <option value="s">None Selected</option>
  <option value="s2">Selected</option>
  <option value="s3">Another value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Select2 plugin?

Comment: Like Barmar said, use Select2 plugin.  I use it and override classes to get the color effect I want

Comment: @Barmar not tried Select2 yet. Hope to find solution without external plugins.

Comment: See if this is of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color

Comment: @bindrid it's close. especially this one http://jsfiddle.net/luiscastillo/sFx7f/, but still not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm still confused about what you want to do and specially how you are trying to do it. Right now you are binding a click element to the `select` each time that the `select` is clicked and the value is 0. That means that after a while, many repeated functions with each click on the `select`. I don't know if you need Select2 plugin for what you are trying to do, but to clean the code that you already have.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yep. If you'll open dropdown, hen choose "None Selected", it will close, and become grey again and if you'll open it it it wont become black, even if you'll choose other than "0" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with CSS and a little of JavaScript/jQuery. The idea would be simple:

- Add a HTML5 `data-` attribute (e.g. `data-value`) to the `select` that will have the current value (by default, the first one).

  ```
  <select name="selected" data-value="s">
    <option value="s">None Selected</option>
    <option value="s2">Selected</option>
    <option value="s3">Another value</option>
  </select>
  ```
- Style the `select` and the `option`s with color `#555555`.

  ```
  select, option { color:#555555; }
  ```
- If the `select` has a `data-value` of "s" (the value of the first option), then make it have the light gray color:

  ```
  select[data-value='s'] { color:#c7cacb; }
  ```
- Every time that the select changes value, update the value of the `data-value`

  ```
  $("select").on("change", function() { 
    $(this).attr("data-value", $(this).val());
  }
  ```

By doing that, you will get the desired effect. Here is a sample using your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // wrap all selectors to add ::after in css
  $('select:not([disabled])').wrap('<label class="dropdown">');
  $('select[disabled]').wrap('<label class="dropdownDisabled">');

  // controlling color of elements
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    $(this).attr("data-value", $(this).val());
  });

})
```

```css
select {
  width: 230px;
  height: 46px;
  background: #f1f5f8;
  color:#c7cacb;
  font-size: 16pt;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d6d5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.dropdownlabel {
  display: block; 
  font-size: 16pt; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #d7d6d5;
}

label.dropdown::after {
  content: "\e90e";
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  font-size: 8pt;
  color: #555555;
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-left: -32px;
  pointer-events:none; /* let the click pass trough */
}

select, option {
  color:#555555;
}

select[data-value='s'] {
  color:#c7cacb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="selected" class="dropdownlabel">Dropdown label</label>
<select name="selected" data-value="s">
  <option value="s">None Selected</option>
  <option value="s2">Selected</option>
  <option value="s3">Another value</option>
</select>
```

Now when the `select` is open or when the selected option is not the first one, the colors will be dark gray; and if the selected option is the first one, the color will be light gray.