# How to change style of particular option in select box?

Tags: html, css, select, styles, box

I want to change style (color, borders etc...) of certain option in select box.

Example:

```
<select name="items">
  <option>Select item:</option>
  <option value="item1"> item1 </option>
  <option value="item2"> item2 </option>
  <option vlaue="item3"> item3 </option>
</select>
```

First option " Select item: " don't have any value, it is more like title of item list. But Im curious is it possible to change style of that option, and make it a bit different from other options in select box?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color

Comment: good catch..I taught u wanted to style all options in select box...

Comment: answer edited accordingly and undeleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
select{
  background:red;
}

option:first-child{
  background:yellow;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<select name="items">
  <option>Select item:</option>
  <option value="item1"> item1 </option>
  <option value="item2"> item2 </option>
  <option vlaue="item3"> item3 </option>
</select>
```