# How can I change the background color of option from select tag?

Tags: css, html-select, background-color

I am trying to change the background colour for option from the select tag.

I tried `select > option` but it doesn't work.

My code below:

```
select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url("images/2017_04_form_select.jpg");
  padding-right: 25px;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #bdb9bb;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

select:-moz-focusring {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

select>option {
  background: #e8e4e6;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change select box option background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/how-to-change-select-box-option-background-color)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set a `background-color` for `select option`

```css
select option {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How can we achieve this in Chrome please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just `select.option` ?

Or just `option` ?

Comment: i tried select > option {} and select option {}. Nothing works.

Comment: I think if you write just : option {background: ...; } it will work.