# Set background color of <option> in <select>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the background color of a select option like this:

```
<select>
  <option class="yellow">Option 1</option>
  <option class="blue">Option 2</option>
  <option class="red">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

where the classes would be like this: `background-color: red;`.  The idea is that when the dropdown list is is shown, each option would have the appropriate background color.

It seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but after spending an hour here, I've come across a lot of answers that claim to solve this but they don't actually work.  The options all have the default background color.

Here are some examples that don't work for me with Chrome 83.0.4103.116 and Safari 13.1 on Mac:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43740774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092074 (Changing the select color works but not the option color)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836286

They do work with FF on Mac.

Is this possible with latest Chrome and Safari on Mac?  Javascript solutions ok.

Comment: The code snippet in your third link doesn't work for you?  It's working for me in Chrome.  Is there a specific browser you're using to test and need to support?  That browser itself may not support this.

Comment: All the examples you cited as not working work for me in Chrome and FF

Comment: @David, I'm using latest Chrome on Mac.

Comment: @gaefan: The Mac may be the problem there.  `<select>` and other form elements traditionally use a lot of native OS functionality to render, and that OS may not support styling in that regard.  (I'm honestly surprised the above links even worked in Windows.)  For the most compatability your best bet is probably to use a JavaScript plugin (jQuery has many if you're not against using jQuery, other frameworks have their own if you're already using something) to display a stylized menu from an existing `<select>`.  Or if you're ambitious you can write your own.

Comment: @David, that looks to be a good answer if you are willing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments on the question above...

> I'm using latest Chrome on Mac.

Aye, there's the rub.  (To be honest, I'm actually quite surprised that the links provided work on my Windows workstation.  Historically styling a `<select>` and some other form elements has been a pipe dream.)

Some form elements more so than others, and very much so for `<select>` elements, rely heavily on native OS functionality.  Note how a standard `<select>` with no styling at all looks very different on a Mac than on Windows or Linux for example.  And in this case it sounds like the native OS functionality simply doesn't support styling here.

For the most compatability your best bet is probably to use a [JavaScript](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) [plugin](https://select2.org/) (jQuery has many if you're not against using jQuery, other frameworks have [other options](https://material-ui.com/) if you're already using something) to display a stylized menu from an existing `<select>`. Or if you're ambitious you can write your own.  But the native functionality is at the whim of the OS and will likely continue to be for some time.

Comment: I was already using Bootstrap, so the Bootstrap dropdown was a great solution.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you. I used #id selector in css and it worked :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
        #red{
            background-color: red;
        }
        #yellow{
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        #green{
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
    <select>
        <option id="red">Option 1</option>
        <option id="yellow">Option 2</option>
        <option id="green">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Though I didn't downvote you.  People are being awfully negative on the question and answers here...

Comment: @gaefan Just trying to help mate. I will try it on Mac and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Why its not working in your browser. I tried the same code and it worked in my browser.

```
<select>
  <option class="yellow">Option 1</option>
  <option class="blue">Option 2</option>
  <option class="red">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

and the css code as below :

```
.yellow{
   background-color:yellow;
}

.blue{
     background-color:blue;
 }

.red{
 background-color:red;
 }
```

if it's still not working then I suggest to wrap your options either in  or  tag and apply background-colour property to them.