# How to change the color of a placeholder option in a Select tag?

Tags: html, css, colors, html-select, placeholder

I am trying to change the color of the first option (Business Type) in a select tag to gray so it looks like placeholder text for a text field. I tried several things that did not work. Is there any way this could be done simply with HTML and CSS?

```
    <select id="businesstype">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Business Type</option>
        <option value="">Restaurant</option>
        <option value="">Hotel</option>
        <option value="">Café</option>
        <option value="">Shop</option>
        <option value="">Services Agency</option>
        <option value="">NGO</option>
        <option value="">Institution</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change select box option background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/how-to-change-select-box-option-background-color)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Target **select** to change the `selected` color style.
Then, target all **options** from this **select** to reset their inherited color.

```css
#businesstype {
  color: gray;
}

#businesstype option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id="businesstype">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Business Type</option>
  <option value="">Restaurant</option>
  <option value="">Hotel</option>
  <option value="">Café</option>
  <option value="">Shop</option>
  <option value="">Services Agency</option>
  <option value="">NGO</option>
  <option value="">Institution</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#businesstype div[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Also check out: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

Add required in select tag and do like

```
  <select class="form-control form-item__element--select" required>
                      <option  disabled value="">Business Type*</option>
                       <option value="">Restaurant</option>
                       <option value="">Hotel</option>
                       <option value="">Café</option>
```

In CSS

```
.form-item__element--select [disabled] {
  color: #DEDEDE;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
   }
.form-item__element--select:invalid {
   color: #DEDEDE;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 16px;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by just adding following css,

```
#businesstype option[disabled]:first-child {
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Won't this only work if the option that needs to be disabled is the first one?

Comment: That won't work since the `disabled` option is hidden as well.