# How can I style my CheckBoxList in ASP.Net using CSS?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a `CheckBoxList` in ASP.Net and I want to change the background color of the checked `Item`.

How can I do it?
I want to do this using CSS.

My `.aspx` page is:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkdisease" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2">
  <asp:ListItem> Spontaneous bleeding</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>chiae (superficial tiny areas of bleeding into the skin resulting in small reddish spots) , Purpura (easy or excessive bruising),  Spontaneous bleeding from </asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Fatigue</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Prolonged bleeding cuts,</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>DVT (deep vein thrombosi</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered html instead of the asp please (unless you are wanting to add the styles server side)

Comment: [How to change select box option background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/how-to-change-select-box-option-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

`Css` code to change the `background-color`.

```
<style>
.MyClass input[type=checkbox]:checked + label 
{
background-color:red;
} 
</style>
```

And apply the class to your `CheckBoxList`. Like below

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkdisease" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" CssClass="MyClass">
<asp:ListItem> Spontaneous bleeding</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>chiae (superficial tiny areas of bleeding into the skin resulting in 
 small reddish spots) , Purpura (easy or excessive bruising),  Spontaneous bleeding 
 from </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Fatigue</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Prolonged bleeding cuts,</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>DVT (deep vein thrombosi</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
```