# Material-UI: Native Select when using Dark theme on Windows Browsers has white text on white background

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using the Native Select from Material-UI if you use the dark theme then the select dropdown has white text on a white background.

This is seen on the component demo page too when in dark mode:

[image]

Can you change the dropdown background color without changing the actual select background color?

**Edit**: This has been logged as an issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** As of version 3.9.2, this issue has been fixed in Material-UI so the workaround below is no longer necessary.

This should probably be fixed in Material-UI, but you can fix it in a particular use case with the following:

Use the theme to specify the option background color (see [How to change select box option background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/how-to-change-select-box-option-background-color)):

```
const styles = theme => ({
  select: {
    "& option": {
      background: theme.palette.background.paper
    }
  }
});
```

And then use that class on the select:

```
  <Select native className={classes.select}>
```

Here's a modified version of the demo using this:

[image: Edit 2vq8w4nnjn]

Comment: @Daveeeeed Note my update -- this is now fixed in 3.9.2.

Comment: @Rayn Cogswell any idea how to change the default blue color on hover or should I use the other selector rather than native ?

Comment: @Rayn Cogswell I tried  '& option': {
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#657fff !important',
        },
      },

Answer (score -1):

It obviously something that should fixed in the package.

However, I found out that it happends only when using native `<option>` tag. This code if from the problematic demo of theirs:

```
          <Select
            native
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange('age')}
            inputProps={{
              name: 'age',
              id: 'age-native-simple',
            }}
          >
            <option value="" />
            <option value={10}>Ten</option>
            <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
            <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
          </Select>
```

So you have two options:

1. You can style the `option` with css and ovveride the `background` or the `fontcolor` to anything you want.
2. You can use another component in material-ui that works well with inverted situations, which they used in another demo. (Using `MenuItem`), like this:

   ```
         <Select
           multiple
           value={this.state.name}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
           input={<Input id="select-multiple-checkbox" />}
           renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
           MenuProps={MenuProps}
         >
           {names.map(name => (
             <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
               <ListItemText primary={name} />
             </MenuItem>
           ))}
         </Select>
   ```

Watch full example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7m2xpoklvx). (Taken from material-ui [demo page](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/#multiple-select))