# I want to change the background color of the select box

Tags: html, css, select, background-color

I want to change the background color of a select box. The color is #F1C26A
for the background of the selector. i tried changing the color and the background for this.
But don't change.
Any idea?
Thanks for the help

```css
select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
  height: calc(2.25rem + 2px); }

select.form-control:focus::-ms-value {
  color: #F1C26A;
  background-color: #fff; }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-6">
      <select id="Pizzas" name="Pizzas" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" >Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" >Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change select box option background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove -ms-value as it is not supported by most browsers only edge and IE.

```css
select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
  height: calc(2.25rem + 2px); }

select.form-control:focus {
  color: #F1C26A;
  background-color: #fff; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-6">
<select id="Pizzas" name="Pizzas" class="form-control"  >
<option value="1" >Option 1</option>
<option value="2" >Option 2</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work in select item with php query, Any idea why?

Comment: @Fidel I am not quite getting what you are trying to say but still provide your PHP query so that I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background-color` on the `select` itself, like so `select { background-color: #F1C26A; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background option not only select, I recommend using, for example, select2 [select2.org](https://select2.org/).

Background definitely browser, using select2, you can simply change styles.
Of course, there are more variations of change select