# Changing the select background color to blue when pressing the TAB key in Chrome like in IE

Tags: css

In the example below I am trying to change the dropdown to the selection blue background-color '#3390FF' when pressing the TAB key in Chrome like in the IE. Further the blue background-color should be maintained for one option when pressing the up and down arraw. The text color #FFFFFF is required for the text too.

Is there a way to change the background color of select menu to '#3390FF' when pressing the TAB key in Chrome by just using CSS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
select:focus-within{
   background-color: #3390FF;
   color:#FFFFFF;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<h1>The option selected attribute</h1>

<label for="cars1">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="cars2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change select box option background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color)

Comment: No, since I want to change the color to blue for the selected option when pressing the tab key.

Comment: You should add an event listener which match the `9` keyCode (corresponding to the `[Tab]` key) on `keypress`, then change it via JavaScript. I don’t think you can do it just by CSS.