# Select dropdown menu color is different between two machines

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

I have a simple select tag in html without any options inside it. When I open the html file in one machine the menu opened is showing in white color as a background.

[image: Dropdown with White meny]

and the same html file and with same select tag without any options, if i open in another machine then the menu opened is showing in black color.

[image: dropdown with black menu]

Why the color is different between these two machines and what could be done to remove the black color and show white color.

Note: In both machines Microsoft Edge (chromium) browser is used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color

Comment: This will set CSS rule for select element with options, but in my case it i just empty select without any child option elements. The menu dropdown color alone is different in this case. When options are added the style is consistent between two machines

Comment: According to your description, I reproduced the problem in the same version of Edge. But I found that the operating system versions are inconsistent (`win10 20H2 19042.928` and `win10 20H2 19042.1288`). So I want to know if you are testing in the same operating system.

Comment: @XudongPeng unfortunately we couldn't chk in our machines are those have privige access. :-( and I would like to know this issue can be resolved using css?

Comment: @XudongPeng one is running in VMWare - Windows Server 2016 - in this machine only i could see the dropdown in black. How can we fix this using CSS

Comment: I did some tests on this, and I am afraid that this issue cannot be solved with style. You have to add an empty option to it.

Comment: Yes, looks like I have to make changes in entire application.. Thank you @XudongPeng

Comment: We finally disabled the dropdown so that it is not clickable anymore

Answer (score 0):

The two machines may have different versions of Chrome installed. You can check the browser version by looking at `chrome://version/`. So the background color of the selected component is different.

Solution: Use css rules to override the background color of the default selected component, and ensure that the browser versions of the two machines are the same.

Comment: Do note that some elements do not change color and a widget is needed

Comment: Do you mean to use widgets to replace select components?

Comment: Yes. Like select2

Comment: Yes the browser version is same between two machines and when i set background color to it - the select element is getting the color. The menu item dropdown is stll showing in black.

Note: I don't have any options inside select element.

Comment: @michael-an Is it because of system theme, I mean does chromium browsers uses style based on system theme

[link]https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=230258

Comment: @Ambareesh Thank you. The system theme is indeed different.