# Coloured boxes in select options

Tags: html

I wan't to do like coloured boxes in select options:

```html
<select name="" id="dfads">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="a"><span style="background:red">##</span> A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

The background work doesn't work in select option. Is it possible such simply?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change select box option background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color)

Comment: Are you trying to set the background of the option in the dropdown list, or the background of the select box when that specific option is selected? (The latter is possible, the former will be pretty unreliable due to the range of ways different browsers handle drop-downs)

Comment: `<span>` isn't a valid child of an `<option>` as far as I know. Use a custom dropdown without `<select>` and JS if you need this level of styling control, or style the whole `<option>`.