# how to change background color of input group items when they hover in bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a select element with some option items and I want to change the blue background color of items (option) when they hover.
here is the bootstrap 5 code:

```html
        <div class="input-group">
          <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect04" aria-label="Example select with button addon">
            <option selected>Choose Your operating System</option>
            <option value="1">Windows</option>
            <option value="2">Mac</option>
            <option value="3">Linux</option>
          </select>
          <button class="btn download-btn" type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change select box option background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color)

Comment: Hi my friend. that was not the answer of my question. at that question the background of option items of a select tag changes but wat I want is to change the default blue color when you hover the option items

Comment: There are only a few style attributes that can be applied to an <option> element. Please read here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208814/1923139