# Change select background color in css

Tags: css, select

My problem is simple, I have a dark background, and the default white color of select is too problematic.

[image]

I tried changing it with background-color but it doesn't work.
The only solution I have is using box-shadow like that:

```css
select { box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px rgb(41,40,59) inset; color: rgb(200,200,200); }
```

But then, it hides the arrow.

[image]

(It also does it when I use another color, that's not the background's color fault.)

What can I do?

Comment: Please attach a code so we can help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change select box option background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with `background-color` seems to work fine, also with arrow.

[image]

if you mean style the childs of dropdown,

then use this selector ✅ `option` instead of ❌ `select`

[image]

```css
select {
  background-color: blue; /* works fine */
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}


/* you can style childs like this */

select option {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Okay, that worked. I don't know why but it didn't when I first tried background-color. I wonder why.