# Use different colors for a <select>'s button and dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to customize the colors of `<select>` dropdown lists in my site. Just setting the `background-color` changes both the button and menu colors. I tried setting the `background-color` on `<option>`s, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836286), but it leaves little areas of parent background on the tops and bottoms of the menus on Firefox. Things get even worse when `:hover` is involved.

[image]

Is there an easy way to solve this in 2023? Perhaps some pseudo-class I'm unaware of? This question is primarily about Firefox. Chrome is already producing workable results.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b5wo3adp/