Change select option background
I want to change select option background without expand block.
If I code like "background: 'red'", it will change all background includes of expand block.
How can I solve it?

<select> are notoriously difficult to style.  You might find it easier to replace it with something like [tag:select2] (maybe there's a [tag:reactjs] equivalent) that you can actually style.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color#

Does this answer your question? Change select box option background color

You'll need to create a class with a name "active" or something similar, and then first remove the it class name from all nodes on click, and finally apply it to the node that you actually want.


function onClick(id) {
  let clickedElement = null;
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  
  elements.forEach((element) => {
  if (element.id === String(id) && !element.classList.contains('active')) {
     clickedElement = element;
  }
  
     element.classList.remove('active');
  })

  if (clickedElement) {
     clickedElement.classList.toggle('active');
  }
 }
.container {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 4px;
}
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
<div>
  <div id="1" onclick="onClick(1)" class="container">
     1
  </div>
  <div id="2" onclick="onClick(2)" class="container">
     2
  </div>
  <div id="3" onclick="onClick(3)" class="container">
     3
  </div>
</div>




Unsure how this answer the question. OP hasn't shown any code and is talking about the background of an option element which isn't even used here



    select {
      background: blue;
      color: #fff;
    }
    select option {
      background: #e2a504;
      color: #fff;
    }
    <select>
      <option val="">Please choose</option>
      <option val="1">Option 1</option>
      <option val="2">Option 2</option>
      <option val="3">Option 3</option>
      <option val="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>




you use the select and select option selector based on that you can change the color here is an example code

To change the background color of the select options without affecting the expanded block, you can use the option selector in CSS. Here's an example:
select {
  background-color: red;
}

select option {
  background-color: white; /* or any other color */
}

