# IE not rendering ASP.net dropdown styles

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, web

I have following Dropdown

`<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="uxStatus" CssClass="Dropdown">`

`<asp:ListItem Text="Select Status" Value="Select Status"></asp:ListItem>`

`<asp:ListItem Text="On Going" Value="On Going"></asp:ListItem>`

`<asp:ListItem Text="Closed" Value="Closed"></asp:ListItem>`

`</asp:DropDownList>`

also this css

```
       .Dropdown
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.Dropdown Option
{
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

with this code,the default text   **Select Status** should be in bold and other items are in normal font. It works perfectly in Chrome,FireFox etc. But items remains bold in IE. Any suggestions like scripts or css?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to the way that Internet Explorer renders `select` lists, the individual `option` tags cannot be styled in the manner you require.

See [Styling options in bold in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655625/styling-options-in-bold-in-internet-explorer) for more information on the reasons.