# HTML font weight property on OPTION of HTML SELECT

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

`font-weight : bold` not works on Option of HTML SELECT in Internet Explorer , is there any other way to specify bold type attribute on option of HTML SELECT.

```css
.test {
    color:black !important;
    font-weight:bold !important;
}
.test1 {
    margin-left:10px !important;
}
```

```html
 <select  ng-model="fields[filter.id]" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
  <option class="test">zero</option>
  <option class="test1">one</option>
 </select>
```

These css styles are working in Firefox but having no effect in chrome and IE :(

Comment: Can you post your code? I'm pretty sure the selector is not good.

Comment: plz create a fiddle for demo :|

Comment: You should test better before posting: it's not working on IE, like many things that work in normal internet browsers...

Comment: @Lukasz Lech I have updated the question with proper code.

Comment: The proper code would be HTML code, not the code from which it is generated. For example, `ng-model` is not an HTML attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling options in bold in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655625/styling-options-in-bold-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela. I have shown actual code from which I have render select option.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using

```css
select{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>aaa</option>
  <option>bbb</option>
</select>
```

should work. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQxRA/1

Comment: If you add some more options you'll notice that only the selected value is bold

Comment: It's not what OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Since IE won't accept BOLD in select option, the only way to do this is to recreate the dropdown list with some script like this one :
http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#HTMLOptionSupport

Comment: It could work, but link-only ansers are discouraged (and sometimes hunted down and punished) on SO. You should post valid code HERE.

Comment: I agree but, if no other solution (i believe) than what is shown on this page, am i supposed to past all the plugin code HERE ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<select>
<option class="AllOptions" >
Option 1
</option>
<!--Add this class To All Options-->
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.AllOptions {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or you can:

```
select {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or you can(But it is deprecated and not valid HTML 5 and bad practice):

```
<select>
<option>
<b>Option1</b>
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Both are not working on IE, but actually it's OP who failed to write he has problem with internet explorer, and not internet browser...

Comment: Yes I have updated code as per your suggestion but CSS changes are only reflecting in firefox not in chrome and IF :(

Comment: @Vladh The simplest solution is <b></b> worked on IE , and IE mobile.you could try the hard way by rebuilding the Sepect Element using Javascript it is easy if you want any help just tell me

Comment: I know that if you use the `<b>` tag it will work, that's why I used the first example in that fiddle