# Style option tag of dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I'm using Jquery Chosen to style my dropdown but I want to style the option tag/the text within the dropdown. I would like it to appear as "**SomeText:** Some more Text". Does anyone know if this is possible?

I downloaded this library - https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui after reading this post [Create a styled Dropdown like on jquery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923233/create-a-styled-dropdown-like-on-jquery-ui) but it doesn't look like I can do partial bold of the tag? The examples seem to be all bold or none.

Comment: I didn't find a specific solution for this but decided to use the optgroup tag and that gives a similar look/feel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, But I just created this dropdown myself.

I have created a script and style to make a button open/show a list to create the illusion of a .

Download the nuGet: [Dropdown-jn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dropdown-jn/1.0.1).

with Package Manager Console write:

> PM> Install-Package Dropdown-jn -Version 1.0.1

Or search for it in the "Manage NuGet Packages".

Hope someone finds this useful. And dont forget to load the css and javascript else the "dropdown" looks really bad ;)